# Execution of code in javascript should be one after another

Tags: javascript, cordova, for-loop

I have two for loops in a function in javascript and it should execute one after another strictly:-

I have set first-one as timeout because i need that to be executed after few seconds.

This is the code:-

```
setTimeout(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < myimg.length; i++) {
        // do something
    }
}, 5000);
for (var j = 0; j < myimg.length; j++) {
    // do something else
}
```

I want the first for loop to execute and then only should the second execute.
But this is currently not the case.
I have tried writing both of them in different functions and executing them as :-

```
for1();
for2();
```

But it is not working by this way also.

Please suggest something

Regards
Abhishek

Comment: Move the 2nd loop into the `setTimeout` callback too?

Comment: it affects the first for loop such that the first one runs again as many times as the second does

Comment: ......huh?  That comment no sense.

Comment: try using this library which will allow you to sequence your task flexibly - https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < myimg.length; i++) {
    // do something
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < myimg.length; j++) {
    // do something else
  }

}, 5000);
```

Comment: it affects the first for loop such that the first one runs again as many times as the second does

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
setTimeout(function(){
  for (var i=0; i<myimg.length; i++)
  {
    // do something
  }                               

  for(var j=0;j<myimg.length;j++)
  {
    // do something else
  }
},5000);
```

Comment: it affects the first for loop such that the first one runs again as many times as the second does

Comment: So you want to run the first loop once and only after that run the second loop as many times as necessary?

Comment: First loop runs and then the second without affecting each other but 1st should only run after one completes and not between the execution

Comment: What are you REALLY trying to accomplish? We're getting contradicting information from you.

Comment: i want the first loop to run first and alone and when that finishes it the second loop should start and finish